# How to ensure that UIImage is never released?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, uiimageview, uiimage

I grabbed the crash log from the iPhone:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000c
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x30011940 objc_msgSend + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x30235f1e CFRelease + 98
2   UIKit                           0x308f4974 -[UIImage dealloc] + 36
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30236b72 -[NSObject release] + 28
4   UIKit                           0x30a00298 FlushNamedImage + 64
5   CoreFoundation                  0x30250a20 CFDictionaryApplyFunction + 124
6   UIKit                           0x30a0019c _UISharedImageFlushAll + 196
7   UIKit                           0x30a00730 +[UIImage(UIImageInternal) _flushCacheOnMemoryWarning:] + 8
8   Foundation                      0x3054dc7a _nsnote_callback + 178
9   CoreFoundation                  0x3024ea52 _CFXNotificationPostNotification + 298
10  Foundation                      0x3054b854 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 64
11  Foundation                      0x3054dbba -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:] + 14
12  UIKit                           0x30a00708 -[UIApplication _performMemoryWarning] + 60
13  UIKit                           0x30a006a0 -[UIApplication _receivedMemoryNotification] + 128
14  UIKit                           0x30a005d0 _memoryStatusChanged + 56
15  CoreFoundation                  0x30217410 __CFNotificationCenterDarwinCallBack + 20
16  CoreFoundation                  0x3020d0aa __CFMachPortPerform + 72
17  CoreFoundation                  0x30254a70 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 2296
18  CoreFoundation                  0x30254164 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 44
19  GraphicsServices                0x3204529c GSEventRunModal + 188
20  UIKit                           0x308f0374 -[UIApplication _run] + 552
21  UIKit                           0x308eea8c UIApplicationMain + 960
...
...
```

From my previous question, [Can somebody give me a hand about this stacktrace in iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248810/can-somebody-give-me-a-hand-about-this-stacktrace-in-iphone-app), I have changed my codes mainly around UIImage part. I now use [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile ... ]. No more [UIImage imageNamed: ... ] or the like. The portion is below.

```
//this is a method of a subclass of UIImageView.
    - (void) reviewImage: (bool) review{
        NSString* st;
        if (review){
        NSString* origin = [NSString stringWithString: [[ReviewCardManager getInstance] getCardImageString:chosenIndex]];
        NSString* stt = [origin substringToIndex: [origin length]-4];

        st = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: stt];

        if (myImageFlipped == nil)
        myImageFlipped = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:st ofType:@"png"]];
        [self setImage:myImageFlipped];

        if (notRotated){
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, [MyMath radf:rotate]);
            notRotated = false;
        }
    }else{
        st = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"sc%d", chosenNumber];

        if (myImage == nil)
        myImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:st ofType:@"png"]];

        [self setImage:myImage];

        if (notRotated){
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, [MyMath radf:rotate]);
            notRotated = false;
        }

    }
    [st release];
}
```

I also have the UIImage already retained in the property.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage* myImage, *myImageFlipped;
```

Memory Leaks have also been taken cared of. These variables are release in dealloc method.

I thought that I have successfully killed the bug, but it seems that I still have a rare occuring bug problem.

Based on the crash log, my application yells out "performMemoryWarning". I am just "alloc"-ing 13 .png images with the size 156 x 272. I'm confused. Those images shouldn't take that much memory to the point that it exceeds iPhone's RAM. Or is there something I am overlooking? Please advise.

Comment: Your property appears to be called "myImage", yet your setter is called "setImage:". Could you please explain what's going on here?

Comment: I am subclassing UIImageView and this class has 2 UIImage. When I want to change the image of the UIImageView, I basically call setImage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. I forgot to change UIImage at one place. Now, all UIImages are truly "alloc", no more autorelease.

FYI, if you are using [UIImage imageNamed: ... ], use "Simulate Memory Warning" on iPhone Simulator to see whether you are having a problem with it when the real device is low on memory.

Answer (score 0):

To help you with memory issues and UIImages, you might want to use the imageNamed convience method of UIImage, from the docs:

`This method looks in the system caches for an image object with the specified name and returns that object if it exists. If a matching image object is not already in the cache, this method loads the image data from the specified file, caches it, and then returns the resulting object.`

Alternatively, you might want to go [this route](http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2009/01/13/imagenamed-is-evil/) if you still run into memory issues after switching to UIImage imageNamed, because there are some downsides to using the convinience method.

Comment: No, the poster already mentioned they had moved *away* from imageNamed, which would be what I would have recommended in order to address those memory warnings, as imageNamed's cache is outwith the programmer's control.

Comment: Ah, i read over that section. In that case, a custom cache like in the linked blog post would then make more sense.