# Problem dismissing multiple modal view controllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am having trouble getting my modal view controllers to display properly. I **have a parent view controller that is the delegate for modal view A**. In modal view A I am presenting modal view B, and having the delegate dimiss modal view A.

When modal view B appears it seems to display but the screen dims, and the UI locks up, but the app doesn't crash. I set animation settings to NO and I am still getting the same issue.

Order of events:

1. Parent View show Modal View A
2. Modal View A shows Modal View B in Modal View A controller
3. Parent View dismisses Modal View A in Modal View A controller via delegation
4. This is where my UI hangs, I can see Modal View B but can't click on it, or do anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by having my parentViewController act as the delegate. Here is my order:

```
[parentView presentViewController:modalViewControllerA animated:YES]
[parentView dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
[parentView presentViewController:modalViewControllerB animated:YES]
//Modal B dismisses himself
```

In my delegate method, I needed to make sure that I dismissed Modal A before presenting Modal B

Answer (score 19):

You could use this

```
[[[self presentingViewController] presentingViewController]  dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Is there a way to have the intermediate view controller not show when dismissing? e.g. A presents B which presents C. From C, self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController.dismissViewController(), but B flashes during the transition. I'd rather just have C slide down and A appear.

EDIT: Looks like just a bug since iOS 8 :(

Comment: @dfickling , Have you got any solution for that issue?

Answer (score 4):

A modal view controller must have a parent view controller in order to display.  If you dismiss the parent view controller ("modal view A", in your case), behavior will be unpredictable.

If you're certain that nested modal view controllers are what you really want, you'll need to dismiss them in reverse order; wait until you're done with "B", then dismiss "B", then dismiss "A".

If you don't need the modal presentation style, you would be better off using a UINavigationController to maintain your stack of view controllers.

**Update**: here is how I would rearrange your order of events.  Presented as code for clarity.

1. `[parentView
   presentViewController:modalViewControllerA
   animated:YES]`
2. `[modalViewControllerA
   presentViewController:modalViewControllerB
   animated:YES]`
3. `[modalViewControllerA
   dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]`
4. `[parentView
   dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]`

Comment: I modified my question, and display my order of events. I am dismissing them in reverse order.

Comment: Are you dismissing Modal View B before step 3?  If not, that order still looks incorrect to me.

Comment: I am not dismissing Modal View B before step 3. I have a cancel and done button in Modal View B that will dismiss itself. I was hoping I could dismiss Modal View A, do some work in Modal View B, and dismiss himself.

Comment: That is fine, but you should wait until you dismiss Modal View B to dismiss Modal View A.  It will look the same to the user, but won't create this problem.

Comment: In my code, parentView implements the delegate protocol (dismissModal) for Modal View A. If I am in Modal View A, and I call Modal View B, where do I dismiss Modal View A?

Comment: If View Controller B has been created by View Controller A, then you can't dismiss A and expect Modal View B to function correctly.  You must first finish your work in B, dismiss it, then dismiss A.

You should dismiss Modal View A in the ParentView, or Modal View A could dismiss itself once it knows that Modal View B has finished. That may not be the most proper practice, but it works.

Comment: @Sheehan: A hackish way to do it in dismissModal with an economy of code would be `if (self.modalViewController.modalViewController) [self.modalViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO]; [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];`

Comment: @Eric - how can I notify Modal View A that Modal View B has finished?

Comment: @Tom - I tried out your code, I get the same results. Modal View B appears, but the screen is locked up.

Comment: You might be running into another problem that can occur when you present or dismiss two view controllers in a single iteration of the run loop.  Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412021/iphone-crashing-when-presenting-modal-view-controller

Comment: Whats interesting is, when I have my delegate handle presenting Modal View A and Modal View B I get strange errors. The parentView won't display Modal View B but can dismiss Modal View A

Comment: @Tom - tried out the link about the run loop. Same results unfortunately.

Comment: Brilliant!  I had been using `[self dismissModalViewController...]` from within the modal view controllers fine - until I nested them.  Fortunately I needed to have a local property pointer to the parent view controller, so I now do `[parentViewController dismiss...]`, and that fixed the nested issue!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For `iOS 6+` and `- presentViewController:animated:completion:`

```
[[[self presentingViewController] presentingViewController]  dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

in Swift 2.1

you can try

```
self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

works for me

View A -> View B -> View C

Apply this code in view C , you will be landing to View A

Answer (score 0):

may be after long but.. I am in same problem and this is the only post with some answer. 
I am not getting what you mean by setting delegate of a parentViewController to self is not allowed .

what I am doing right now is

```
[self presentModalViewController:ViewControllerA animated:YES];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];// inside ViewControllerA
[self presentModalViewController:ViewControllerB animated:YES];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];// inside ViewControllerB
```

Problem is after viewControllerA , viewControllerB view is not presenting.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I have a main view and need to show a modalview1 where a button present a modalview2. Looks the same you needed.
But there is a button in the modalview2 which forwards to the main view.

**So the solution is:**
Main view presents UINavigationController with modalview1 as rootController. Then modalview1 present modalview2 by "[self.navigationController modalview2 animated:YES];".

When modal2 needs to forward to the main view, just make "[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];" and UINavigationController is hidden.

Hope it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

Dismiss all views:

```
[self dismissModalViewController animated:YES];
[self dismissModalViewController animated:YES];
[self dismissModalViewController animated:YES];
[self dismissModalViewController animated:YES];
```

(one for each added modal view)

then present a new modal view controller

Comment: With this solution, how do ModalViewControllers lower in the order know when the ones above have been dismissed?

Answer (score 0):

Apple document about [dismiss(animated:completion:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss) method.

In section `Discussion`, it said:

```
any intermediate view controllers are simply removed from the stack.
```

> If you present several view controllers in succession, thus building a stack of presented view controllers, calling this method on a view controller lower in the stack dismisses its immediate child view controller and all view controllers above that child on the stack. When this happens, only the top-most view is dismissed in an animated fashion; **any intermediate view controllers are simply removed from the stack.** The top-most view is dismissed using its modal transition style, which may differ from the styles used by other view controllers lower in the stack.

In other words, if the view controller stack like following

```
Root -> A -> B -> C -> D ... -> Z
```

`D` calls `dismiss` method, all view controllers behide `D`, ex: `(E ... Z)`, will be removed from the stack.