# iOS Dismis stack of ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I'm developing a iPhone App, in which I'm changing the ViewController using presentModalViewController method upto 2/3 levels (e.g. Home-->Option-->Other-->More).

Now I want to get my app back to first screen or ViewController. If I use dismissModalViewControllerAnimated method, it just dismisses the current view controller only. But I want to clear the stack and start the Home screen again.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Seems like a repeat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474314/problem-dismissing-multiple-modal-view-controllers

Comment: good question..are you asking to go back to main menu altogether..or simply by dismissing each view animated?coz..i would like to know the former

Comment: I want to go back to Main Menu dismissing all ViewControllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the delegates properly for each level. So if you press Cancel or Done in More, it will call somehting like `[other moreViewDidCancel]` inside of which, you will call `dismissModalViewController:Animated:` and notify its parent view controller (delegate) that is should dismiss( so, `[option otherViewDidCancel]`) and so on till the top level.

Comment: hey..man..although you did answer..i knew that method..but if you could know how to present the home screen without being animated..i had the same problem.what if i just want to come back to main menu...not just playing animation that you ar going back views..

Comment: you can set `animated` parameter to NO and you will skip the animation